# Android: Facebook Login

Tags: android

I have made a programme in which the is a login button for facebook,, the loads the facebook login page,, but instantainously control returns to the same. window comprising login button...
Also the same programme is finely executing on Emulator.

Comment: Do u have facebook app intall in ur device.....

Answer (score 1):

look in the Facebook developers API documentation.

the problem is as Anshuman said, that you already have a SSO on your phone, and trying to authenticating again results in a problem, you need to override the `onActivityResult` and do the special facebook's `authorizeCallback` function:

it goes something like this:

```
            facebook.authorize(SinglePost.this, permissions,
                new DialogListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                        // control comes here if the login was successful
                        // Facebook.TOKEN is the key by which the value of
                        // access token is stored in the Bundle called
                        // 'values'
                        Log.d("COMPLETE", "AUTH COMPLETE. VALUES: "
                                + values.size());
                        Log.d("AUTH TOKEN",
                                "== " + values.getString(Facebook.TOKEN));
                        updateStatus(values.getString(Facebook.TOKEN));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                        Log.d("FACEBOOK ERROR",
                                "FB ERROR. MSG: " + e.getMessage()
                                        + ", CAUSE: " + e.getCause());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(DialogError e) {
                        Log.e("ERROR", "AUTH ERROR. MSG: " + e.getMessage()
                                + ", CAUSE: " + e.getCause());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        Log.d("CANCELLED", "AUTH CANCELLED");
                    }
                });

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d("onActivityResult", "onActivityResult");
    facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use facebook api.......

http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2011/02/28/30-minute-guide-integrating-facebook-android-application/ checkout this , click on right if its helpful